# What is .htaccess file. Why we use this file. what are the advantages of using this file?

Tags: .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is .htaccess file in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170819/what-is-htaccess-file-in-php)

As per my research this file is used for Url rewrites.

Comment: Show some research. You can come to know what is htaccess from various website. Do a search, if its unclear , and your struggling and have searched enough then post it

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to set or modify per-directory configuration settings without having to change configuration files or restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess allows you to micromanage permissions.  Apache generally discourages its use unless it's overriding a general behavior since it can be slower (if parent folder does not contain .htaccess, it must then check the parent of parent folder for .htaccess on up to the root folder).

However that doesn't mean it can't be useful, simply that you must be tactful in its usage.  Where general apache configuration is to a bulldoser, .htaccess would be to a shovel.  Just know when to pick a bulldoser over a shovel and you'll be fine.

[A decent article can be found here regarding .htaccess.](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml)