# Masking URL in HTML

Tags: url-masking

I have one HTML page. Assume the URL is

```
http://localhost/local/local.html
```

but i want to mask the URL as

```
http://localhost/local/abc
```

can we do like this?

Comment: always post your efforts with questions

Comment: @utility.....That is my doubt whether that is possible or not . If possible how?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.htaccess` file in your root of your domain and add the following in that file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^local.html$ http://localhost/local/abc/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: you don't have to create `abc.htaccess` just create simple `.htaccess` with no name. If an error occurs saying `Invalid File Name` then just create a new file and give name as `.htaccess.` (note that there's a period before and after "htaccess"

Comment: I am using IIS, In wwwroot folder i have created ".htaccess" (*.*) and i have added above code as RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Ifa_Reportsmry.cshtml$ http://localhost/local/abc/ [R=301,L] and the url is :http://localhost/svymanalysis/Ifa_Reportsmry.cshtml.

Comment: the solution mentioned above works for apache web server. If you're using IIS, then refer to this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997830/how-can-i-enable-url-rewrite-module-in-iis-8-5-in-server-2012

Comment: I will check that...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `.htaccess` add lines:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?query=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When you visit `https://localhost/local/abc` in `index.php` parse `$_GET["query"]` how you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the required action using a `htaccess` rule ,

Learn about htaccess at :

**[What is .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170819/what-is-htaccess-file)**

`.htaccess` rule you can implement is follows :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^local/local.html (.*)$ http://localhost/local/abc$1 [r=301,nc]
```