# how htaccess rewrite works

Tags: php, .htaccess

How the htaccesss code works and how they used to redirect the link 
why index.php is used??

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /XYZ/
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170819/what-is-htaccess-file)

Comment: its slight different i think

Comment: I think you asked about how the code work not how .htaccess works? Right?

Comment: yes mate, but if get explanation of how .htaccess works than it will be plus point

Comment: It would help if you'd narrow down what you *do* understand about this and what specifically you *don't*.

Comment: Is my answer sufficient for you to understand @Satish51? if yes mark my answer as solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On # Enable the rewrite engine

RewriteBase /XYZ/ #The base url can also be called as root url

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L] #Content between ^ $ are rewritten [L] is a flag

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Don't select files

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #Don't select directory
```

Check about flags in Apache docs https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Have more question ask in comment.

Side note
Use this if you have multiple conditions

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```